# Quicktime PNG codecs turn blue on most recent Premiere Pro CC update

Tags: premiere, codec, quicktime, color

I recently updated my copy of Premiere CC to 2015.4, and many of my downloaded effects overlay videos turned blue. (Attached is a blood spray effect). These were all downloaded from the website FootageCrate and are in the "PNG, Timecode" mov format (according to Finder's metadata). I can't simply revert my version of Premiere (at least I don't think so) because I've done some other edits in the current project which had to be converted for the new version.

When I open these in Quicktime, they convert to a different format but lose their alpha channel.

[image: An example of the blue Quicktime PNG]

Thanks!